# Mapbox (walking) directions api suggest ferries to cross the river instead of using bridges

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-api-directions

I am using **Directions Api** (important - walking mode), **v5 version**.
App works in London. When I select point A on the left side of the river, point B on the right, map usually suggests using ferry. There are 10s of bridges around, we really need walking route.

Are there any solutions how to fix this? **"Exclude" property** (Exclude ferry) doesn't work for walking mode. Cycling mode is much better but we must use walking one. So it looks we can't avoid river transport

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a feedback from Mapbox team, they have added new option to exclude ferry for walking route type. All works great!
https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/directions/